# How to insert first subfigures with caption in IEEE ACCESS LaTeX?

Tags: floats

I want to insert first subfigures with caption in IEEE Access LaTeX by using `subfloat` but I can't do, 
because I think It can be only able to insert after using

```
\Figure(topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){filename}{caption\label{}}
```

If I can't write step1 code, step2 code does not working,
How can I solve this problem?

## codes

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
    \usepackage[caption=false, font=normalsize, labelfont=sf, textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
\usepackage[caption=false, font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi
\begin{document}

%%% problems ...... 
\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){Fig1_A.eps}
{(a) ${x}^H$, (b) $x^{IVS}$, $(c) x^{FSDD}$, $(d) x^{ENM}$, $(e)     x^{SEG}$. Samples of a cropped full face image and several kinds of sub-images.\label{fig:Fig1}}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5in]{Fig1_A.eps}
\label{fig:Fig1_A}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{
\includegraphics[width=0.5in]{Fig1_B.eps}
\label{fig:Fig1_B}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{
\includegraphics[width=0.5in]{Fig1_C.eps}
\label{fig:Fig1_C}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{
\includegraphics[width=0.5in]{Fig1_D.eps}
\label{fig:Fig1_D}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5in]{Fig1_E.eps}
\label{fig:Fig1_E}}
\caption{(a) ${x}^H$, (b) $x^{IVS}$, $(c) x^{FSDD}$, $(d) x^{ENM}$, $(e) x^{SEG}$. Samples of a cropped full face image and several kinds of sub-images.}
\label{fig:Fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please give a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code, we usually want to test answers, and typing it off a screenshot is just annoying and unnecessary. Also wouldn't hurt to add a link to the class (http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/use-authoring-tools-and-ieee-article-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-ieee-access/), as it's not a standard one.

Comment: Was the subfig package loaded?

Comment: sorry, I don’t know that. I edited my post to show my codes. I downloaded latex template from that link and read Author guide line. I want to insert my figures not to use ‘\Figure[t!] ~~~’. how can I do that...? thanks

Comment: Yes I loaded subfig package like “\ifCLaSSOPTIONcomposoc ~ \fi”.

Comment: If I removed this code “\Figure[t!\(topskip=0pt){}”, I can’t insert next figures. this error message is shown. “Undefined sequneces ~~”

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems unavoidable.

If you use `\Figure` for a single image you want to show, then you can use `\subfigure` for multiple images later, without problems.

But if there is not `\Figure` anywhere in your code, then you are gonna get log errors about captions in all the typical `figure` enviroments.

Hope they fix that problem with the template.